# Unable to connect to Z/OS by ssh

Tags: openssh, zos

I am trying to establish a ssh session between my windows client and zOS server but the connection is closed after password checking

Please can you help to understand the openssh log?

Best regards and thanks in advance

Horacio Merovich

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 192.168.211.2 ([192.168.211.2]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT is supported. Reading the VTSequence from console
debug1: ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING is supported. Console supports the ansi parsing
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to 192.168.211.2 closed.
Transferred: sent 2400, received 2952 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 19749.0, received 24291.3
debug1: Exit status 1
```

Comment: What do the logs on the z/OS side say?

Comment: Probably a better fit for ServerFault. This isn't really within the purview of SO.